# Angular 2 ng-if fails

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

Trying to apply css styles dynamically for the element which has ng-if condition.
Works fine, if the condition is true. Is there any way that I can modify the element even if the condition fails. I know I can find the element (by getElementsByClassName) and modify but is there any other better solution other than this?

ex:

```
<span *ngIf="orderBy=='asc'" [ngStyle]="{'height': value+ '%'}"></span>                              
    <span *ngIf="orderBy=='desc'" [ngStyle]="{'height': value+ '%'}"></span>
```

Comment: How about using `*ngIf="orderBy=='asc'"` and `*ngIf="orderBy!='asc'"` ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use ngClass for that. Add class based on the conditional value.

```
[ngClass]="{orderBy=='asc'? 'someclass': 'otherclass'}"
```

You can write seperate styles for each of the class.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ng-class to achieve this

ng-class="{'*classname*':orderBy==='asc',
                 '*classname*':orderBy==='desc'}"